# Rogue assassin, potential for double crit?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, critical-hit, assassin

Let's assume a rogue assassin level 5 with the 5thE
Assassinate. When an enemy hasn’t taken a turn yet, you get advantage and, if they are surprised, any hit is critical.

I am wondering if you roll a natural 20 in this situation where any hit is considered critical already, will it be a "double critical" or give you any type of bonus for rolling 20? I am assuming no but wanted to check!

Comment: Hi Lyft--this looks to be a duplicate of the linked question. If you look over there and don't see what you're looking for addressed, could you please [edit] this post to make clearer the distinction and flag it for review? Thanks.